# show image using reactjs in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I am doing some tiny stuffs in reactjs in a blade file of laravel. I just add react   cdn and writing code within script tag.
All looks good except I stuck at a point of showing image from public/assets/img folder of laravel using reactjs.

Any help is appretiated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the source link of your image.

For example, if laravel expose those static files under `http://localhost/public/asset/img`, then you need to write in your JSX:

```
<img src="http://localhost/public/asset/img/test.jpg" alt="test" />
```

Comment: In that case I am getting dependent in the source code. If my host get changes I would need to edit everywhere I used it.
Think about laravel asset() function where I dont need to change anything even if host changes.

Comment: Abdur Rahman, react does not provide anything else than a virtual DOM, if you want to add some configuration, you should create a configuration variable with what you need for booting your react app. You could use the context to broadcast down your react tree when you need it. Another option would be to use `<base />` tag

Answer (score 0):

Dimitri Kopriwa's answer didn't work for me because including public in the image path meant I was repeating it twice. When you start a PHP project you're already in the public directory so using this worked for me:
`http://localhost:8000/documents/pictures/${image}`

Answer (score 0):

it's simple, if your image is located in **public/assets/img**, write this in your jsx:

`<img src="http://localhost/public/asset/img/image.png" alt="image" />`