# How can I use a local image in my React component in my Laravel project?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, image, components

I have an issue, as stated in the title. No other post really managed to help me, unfortunately.

Basically all I am trying to do, is to display an image in my component, which is going to be a paginator. All of this is inside a Laravel project though.

So this is Paginator.js (really incomplete), at /resources/js/components/Paginator.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import BackIcon from '../images/back.svg';

export class Paginator extends Component {
    render() {
       return(
            <div className="flex flex-row">
                <button type="button">
                    <svg width="30" height="30">
                        <img src={BackIcon} width="30" height="30" alt="back"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The BackIcon is imported in /resources/js/app.js like this:

```
import BackIcon from './images/back.svg';
```

Running `npm run watch` manages to compile this. Yet the image comes out to be undefined (the component mounts just fine btw). Obviously I checked that it's in the correct folder, which is /resources/js/images/back.svg .

## What I tried

I think the image might need to go into the public folder. So I put it there, but without having  something like `asset('public/images/back.svg')` in a blade template, the image is not going to be included in the public folder; it will show an error during `npm run dev` where it says "module not found".

I was hoping to use webpack.mix.js to include the image in my public folder, so I can just access it via its path in the 'src' argument of my img component. But I don't know if that is even possible.

Just as info to this, my FILESYSTEM_DRIVER in my Laravel project is set to 'local' right now. I know you can change it to 'public' though if that changes anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, thx for responding. When I put the image in the `public` folder and edit app.js in the way you said I get an error when running `npm run dev`: `This dependency was not found: * images/back.svg in ./resources/js/app.js
`.

Comment: Unfortunately that also doesn't work. PHPStorm tells me `Cannot resolve directory 'images' ` and when I go to my page, the image is still not in the public folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show image using reactjs in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062653/show-image-using-reactjs-in-laravel)

Comment: No, that does not work for me.. Still no back.svg in the public/images folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out having `<svg>` tags around my `<img>` wasn't a good idea. Removing them actually fixed it.